# SELECT statement to get sum of grouped columns with column header

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, unnest

Table data:

```
NAME     RS
A        10
A        20
A        30
B        15 
B        5
B        10
C        70
C        30
```

Expected output:

```
A   -- column name
10
20
30
60  -- total of A

B
15
5
10 
30  -- total of B

C
70
30
100 -- total of C
```

So far I have tried:

1. `UNION ALL`
2. Select all datas and manipulated with front end.

Is there any other easiest solution without `UNION ALL`?

Comment: Group Name as a header row,and find the sum of grouped Total Rs(e.g-10+20+30=60).(everything Should be Returned as Row).Am i  clear Now

Comment: You are still listing individual rows for `A`, but not for `C`, which is the unclear part.

Comment: Please edit the question to present the *actually* expected result as expected result.

Comment: Sorry I updated My Question

Answer (score 1):

To do it in a single query with plain SQL:

```
SELECT unnest(arr)
FROM  (
   SELECT ARRAY[name] || array_agg(rs::text) || sum(rs)::text AS arr
   FROM   tbl
   GROUP  BY name
   ) sub
ORDER  BY arr[1];
```

Similar to what [@WingedPanther](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28066574/939860) posted, but clean and safe for any name.

Returns:

```
A
10
20
30
60
B
15
15
C
70
30
100
```

Or:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT name, sum(RS)::text AS sum_rs
   FROM   tbl
   GROUP  BY 1
   )
SELECT unicol
FROM  ( 
   SELECT name AS unicol, name AS order1, 1 AS order2 FROM cte
   UNION  ALL
   SELECT sum_rs, name, 2 FROM cte
   ) sub
ORDER  BY order1, order2;
```

Returns:

```
A
60
B
15
C
100
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cce33/11)

Or just send the result from the CTE and do the rest your client.

Comment: Thank for your reply .I need an output like A 10 20 30 (10 + 20 + 30 = 60 )

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select  unnest(string_to_array( name ||','||rs||','||sum, ',')) AS elem 
from (
     select name
           ,string_agg(rs::text,',')  rs
           ,sum(rs) 
     from tbl 
     group by name
)t
```

If you want print `Total Of` in *Result* use

```
select  unnest(string_to_array( name ||','||rs||','||sum, ',')) AS elem 
from (
     select name
           ,string_agg(rs::text,',')  rs
           ,'Total Of '||name||' '|| sum(rs) sum
     from tbl 
     group by name
)t
```

[**> SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d89fb/3)

Comment: I like the idea to unnest an array (+1) . But it's unsafe to use string concatenation - just build an array to begin with, then you don't depend on the delimiter.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter thanks for the advice, You have already mentioned that in your answer so I don't want to update it my answer (so the future visitors can easily understand  )

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% certain what you're after but sounds like you just want this:

```
Select name, Sum(RS)
from sometable
group by name
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(Name NVARCHAR(MAX), RS INT)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('A', 10),
('A', 20),
('A', 30),
('B', 15),
('C', 70),
('C', 30)
```

With UNION

```
SELECT Name, RS, 0 AS OrderBit FROM @t
UNION ALL
SELECT Name, SUM(RS) AS Total, 1 AS OrderBit FROM @t
GROUP BY Name

ORDER BY Name, OrderBit
```

Without Union:

```
SELECT Name, SUM(RS) AS RS FROM @t 
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((Name), (Name, RS))
```

Comment: GROUPING SETS is it possible in postgresql?

Comment: I have no idea about POSTGRESQL but it seems that it is possible.
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Grouping_Sets

Comment: This is invalid syntax for Postgres.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter are u kidding? Result from fiddle 

You have data

`INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
 ('A', 10),
 ('A', 20),
 ('A', 30),
 ('B', 15),
 ('C', 70),
 ('C', 30)`

And output is 

`A 10 0
A 20 0
A 30 0
A 60 1
B 15 0
B 15 1
C 70 0
C 30 0
C 100 1`

What is incorrect here?

Comment: The 2nd query doesn't work, the 1st doesn't answer the question. Both are OT, since the question tagged Postgres.

Comment: U are kidding again. When I've posted my answer and when you commented on my answer also, the question was not tagged by any tag. It was tagged half an hour after my answer. The 1st query output is 

`A 10 0
A 20 0
A 30 0
A 60 1
B 15 0
B 15 1
C 70 0
C 30 0
C 100 1`

It's exactly what was in question test data and also in my answers's test data. And the output is 

`A 10 0
A 20 0
A 30 0
A 60 1
B 15 0
B 15 1
C 70 0
C 30 0
C 100 1`

Same again. 

Excuse me bu are u troll or what do you want?

Comment: The question was tagged `[postgresql]` from the first moment. Check the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28065481/revisions). Same for your other claims. I am only notified if you @-reply. I am done here, have a nice day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69304/discussion-between-giorgi-nakeuri-and-erwin-brandstetter).